# How to add javascripte in larava

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, computer-science

How to add javascript in laravel.

Error=>Use of undefined constant s - assumed 's'

```
<script>
       function run() {

           var a = document.getElementById("save");

           var value = document.getElementById("selectP").value;

           var s = "Referrdetails/"+value;

           a.href = "{{route(s)}}";

       }

</script>
```

Comment: `route(s)` should be `route('s')` (You need `'` around string values.) Closing as syntax error/typo.

Comment: Please elaborate it.

Comment: you expect it to work like a template?

Comment: no. s is variable

Comment: This will not work.

Comment: yes my file is .blade.php but it still give me error of Use of undefined constant

Comment: because blade is parsing this file and seeing an echo where you then have a call to a function with a constant 's' ... all that javascript is just meaningless TEXT to PHP... the webserver does not process the javascript, the browser does

Comment: Oops, `s` is a JS variable. The syntax is fine, but you can't use `JS` variable in a `php` function (`route()`).

Comment: @TimLewis looks like they want their javascript variable 's' to be used there ... so potentially valid blade syntax but misunderstanding of the parsing of blade and when javascript is ran

Comment: @lagbox Yeah, saw that after the fact; definitely a misunderstanding of when certain pieces of code are executed. `s` is unknown to php when this runs, so even fixing the `undefined constant` with `'s'`, or `$s` would cause other issues.

Comment: there's no way this would work, there can't be a route named `"Referrdetails/"+value` anyway so OP better concatenate a plain old URL string

Comment: true and i wish there was a simple link to send to people to easily clear up this type of misunderstanding

Comment: @Saly3301 i mean you can name a route `Referrdetails/1` if you really wanted to ... but yea that wouldnt make much sense for obvious reasons ... never know what people are thinking :)

Comment: can you have a dynamic name for a route? like `->name('referrdetails.{id}');` ?

Comment: no, i was just saying someone could name routes that way, you wouldn't, but you 'can' do it ... was just being technical :), that is most likely a url/path they want not a route name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use PHP blade functions with dynamically queried javascript variables from the DOM because Blade views are compiled on the server and the resulting HTML is sent back to the browser as it is before your Javascript even loads, just concatenate a URL string instead

Find out what the full URL for `referrdetails` is and concatenate it like so

```
a.href = "/referrdetails/" + value;
```

Or with ES6 templates

```js
a.href = `/referrdetails/${value}`;
```

Hope this helps